# Spark : UnpicklingError: NEWOBJ class argument has NULL tp_new when trying to push the data to Kinesis Firehose

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I am trying to data to kinesis firehose through spark :

I am getting an error like 
UnpicklingError : NEWOBJ Class argument has NULL tp_new

I am using python version : 2.10 (Anaconda version) 
Spark - 2.4.6-hadoop version. 
I am using Boto3 - to push the data to Amazon Kinesis.

When I tried to push the data to kinesis with sample data with python script - it works well and I get the resultant output like shown below..

```
In [21]: aws_client.put_record_batch(DeliveryStreamName='streamname',Records=Records)

And I am getting a success message that it is pushed to kinesis : 

Out[16]: 
{u'FailedPutCount': 0,
 u'RequestResponses': [{u'RecordId': u'gfdgfdgdtgrt4rt4trfg'},
  {u'RecordId': u'hggfhhy7686ghytryhfgfdgdgtrged'}],
 'ResponseMetadata': {'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
  'RequestId': 'u'ytutujguiuuuiiuuu'}}
```

http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/guide/configuration.html
http://boto3.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/services/kinesis.html#client

similarly if i try in spark - (Doing processing for enrichment of tweets from twitter and pushing to kinesis)..

```
sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingKafkaWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)

zkQuorum, topic = sys.argv[1:]
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
enrichedData = lines.flatMap(f1)
enrichedData.foreachRDD(lambda rdd: rdd.foreachPartition(sendToKinesis))
# simplejson.l1oad()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

I am getting an error like 
UnpicklingError : NEWOBJ Class argument has NULL tp_new

[image]

Can anyone help me to figure out why it is not working with Spark?

Comment: If you've solved the problem (as your modification to the question title suggests), then if you have a moment, would you mind writing up an answer describing the solution you discovered? Answering one's own questions is encouraged on StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer